# C++ date & time with milliseconds

Tags: c++, date, time

**Requirement**

I need to retrieve the date and time including milliseconds in C++11 on Windows. If possible, beginning earlier than 1970.

I also need to be able to extract year, month, day, hour, second and millisecond from the date/time variable.

**What I've tried**

- `time()` only returns seconds.
- `clock()` doesn't return a date, only time since last system start. Good for measuring elapsed time, tho.

Note: It only has to work with Windows. Linux is not required.

Comment: *"If possible, beginning earlier than 1970."* Doc Brown, is that you?

Comment: Well, I'm not going back to the past, but what if I want to store someone's birthday who's older than 43? ;)

Comment: If you are to get any *precision* out of the milliseconds, you will have to consider leap seconds and daylight savings time changes for different years. That would be **hard**.

Comment: Birthday with the millisecond granularity? Wow, that's some precision! ;)

Comment: @Bo Persson: the .NET Framework also seems to manage this just fine. I wonder how they do that...

Comment: Also I need this for various purposes. Birthdays are only one example. So milliseconds are indeed important.

Comment: What about using WinAPI?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using c++11, you should use [chrono](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) which allow you to manage time easier.
It gives you a few methods to "cast" your time in whatever units you want (seconds to milliseconds, ...) and can manage ctime variables too.

Comment: @DevilsChild: Yep, that's very welcome, next big thing on the list should be filesystem/network utilities.

Comment: I have one question tho: How can I get the seconds/hour etc. portions from the `time_point`. Like `11.04.2013 20:25` has an hour portion of "20".

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're looking for [`gettimeofday`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/gettimeofday.html).

See e.g. [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/430449b3-f6dd-4e18-84de-eebd26a8d668/) for an implementation for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try looking into boost::posix_time.  The boost::posix_time::ptime has many methods to give you time value in seconds, milliseconds and microseconds. You can also 
do operation directly on the ptime objects.
If you are free to use boost in you project. I would recommend to have a look into it.
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html